# Receiving variables from ajax to php using slim

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, slim

I am getting a 404 error when trying to send a variable or a constant to PHP using slim.

> http://localhost:5000/project/1 (Not Found)

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
         url: path + '/project/1',
         type: 'get',
         dataType: "json",
         //some code
```

**PHP**

```
 $app->get('/project/:id', function ($id, $request) use($servername, $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpassword)
 {
 //some code
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the URL go request like that 
Profile/1

Without/ in first